# How to test an export function which has req as parameter in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I'm really new to react and I've given a code to test.

```
export function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  return {
    props: {
      profit: req.properties.profit,
    },
  };
}

export default function DailyProfit(props) {
  const [pageErrors, setPageErrors] = useState([]);

  return (
    <PageTemplate
      heading="Profit page"
      backLink="/"
      errors={pageErrors}
    >
      <HmpoDatePicker {...props} errorCallback={setPageErrors} />
    </PageTemplate>
  );
}
```

How can I test the first export function `getServerSideProps` I'm really stuck and any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import {getServerSideProps} from 'file_name';

describe('getServerSideProps', () => {
  test('returns properties from request properties', () => {
    const request = {
      properties: { profit: 'someProfit' }
    }
    expect(getServierSideProps({req: request}).props.profit).toEqual(request.properties.profit);
  }); 
});
```

You just call the function with mocked argument so that you are sure that `getServerSideProps` function correctly parses the given object.

Note that above example is written used the `jest` test runner